# Can you load balance multiple ECS containers on a single instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc, amazon-ecs

Is it possible to have a single ELB load balance 4 containers running on 2 EC2 instances?

Example:

```
    ELB--> [Container A] - Instance 1 
       --> [Container B] - Instance 1
       --> [Container C] - Instance 2
       --> [Container D] - Instance 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Look into the new Application Load Balancers. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/

Comment: I don't know how I missed that! I think I got too caught up in forum posts and blog articles that were written before this was released. Thanks!